# Azure DevOps task inline script with powershell does not fails the task on error

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the Azure DevOps **release pipeline** I run **Inline Script** as part of the Post Deployment Action of **Azure App Service Deploy task** (Task version 4.*).

The inline script looks like this:

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File UpdateCSP.ps1 -ApiUrl "$(API_URL) $(API_TESTING_URL)"
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File GenerateVarsJs.ps1 -ApiUrl "$(API_URL)" -IdamAuthServerUrl "$(AUTH_SERVER)" -IdamClientId "$(CLIENT_ID)" -TestApiUrl "$(API_TESTING_URL)"
```

One of the scripts was hard terminated (by invoking `Throw "some error text"`) command. The error was written into the task output but the task itself succeeded.

Hard terminated powershell script returns error code 1. Therefore my expectation was that script failure would also fail the task.

I would need the task to fail in case of script failure (nobody is checking the output of succeeded task). How this could be done?

Comment: @DanielMann As mentioned in the question, it is App Service Deploy task. It has Post Deployment Action where you can specify Inline script. Release pipelines do not support YAML, so it is classic. I believe the info is in the question

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below workarounds. Did it work out?

Answer (score 4):

I carried out a simple test. And it worked fine.

I have a simple command `throw "This is an error.` in the .ps1 file. I call the script in the Post Deployment Action of Azure App Service Deploy task:

[image]

The task failed as expected:

[image]

However, You can have a try using [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#complete-finish-timeline) `#vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed` in the .ps1 file to manually fail the task. See below:

```
Throw "some error text"
Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
```

Or You can try using `[Environment]::Exit($exitCode)` after the `Throw` command in your .ps1 file.

```
 Throw "some error text"
 [Environment]::Exit(1)
```